# Is there a way to override Olark css?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, jsonp

I'm working with Olark chat but seems like the design customization is limited, I'd like to change the background color for example. This is the script that loads Olark chat box.

I was thinking about something like loading a script after X seconds and overrides the CSS file that is loaded by this script but as you can be thinking there's not a way to know how much will take load the CSS file from Olark.

I'm using ruby on rails btw.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async> ;
(function(o,l,a,r,k,y){
    if(o.olark)return;
    r="script";
    y=l.createElement(r);
    r=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
    y.async=1;
    y.src="//"+a;
    r.parentNode.insertBefore(y,r);
    y=o.olark=function(){
        k.s.push(arguments);k.t.push(+new Date)
    };
    y.extend=function(i,j){y("extend",i,j)};
    y.identify=function(i){y("identify",k.i=i)};
    y.configure=function(i,j){y("configure",i,j);
    k.c[i]=j};
    k=y._={s:[],t:[+new Date],c:{},l:a};
})
(window,document,"static.olark.com/jsclient/loader.js");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Create a new rule set inside your CSS file like the following:

```
#olark-wrapper .olark-launch-button {
      width: 60px !important;
      height: 60px !important;
}
```

> Note: width/height are just examples, feel free to use any other
>   fields.

This rule set name gets generated by the the script you mentioned above. However, I do not believe you can change the background color (i.e. `background-color: aqua;`). But Olark provides options on their website to change the colors of the chat icon.